# Hidding A button with JQuery with Conditions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a table called `report`
and currently im trying to read what is the value in the `status` column in order to hide or display the `retryBtn` depending on the value in it.

I have also included the JQuery script by manually copy pasting the code & saving in into a file.
Right now I have wrote a JQuery code that runs on load, but it seems like it wasnt run at all as the log shows nothing. What is the reason that its not running, in the src folder the website is able to detect the `JQuery.js` script.
Any advice?

Table

```html
<div class="table" id="table_report">
    <table class="report" id="report">
        <tr>
            <th class="column">ID</th>
            <th class="column">A</th>
            <th class="column">B</th>
            <th class="column">Status</th>
            <th class="column"> C </th>
            <th class="column">D Path</th>
            <th class="column"> E</th>
            <th class="column">E Path</th>
            <th class="column"> F</th>
            <th class="column">F Path</th>
            <th class="column">G </th>
            <th class="column">G Path</th>
            <th class="column"> </th>
        </tr>
```

```php
while($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            
            $fullPSPath = $G_Path . $row['GPath'];
            $fullEPath = $E_Path  . $row['EPath'];
            $fullDPath = $D_Path  . $row['DPath'];
            $fullFPath = $F_Path  . $row['FPath'];
            echo "<tr>"
            . "<td>". $row['ID']."</td><td>"
                    . $row['A']."</td><td>" .$row['B']. "</td><td><span class='status'>". $row['Status'] . "</span></td><td>"
                    . $row['D']. "</td><td>" . "<a href='download.php?type=D&path=". $fullDPath. "'> $fullDPath</a></td><td>"
                    . $row['E']. "</td><td>". "<a href='download.php?type=E&path=". $fullEPath. "'> $fullEPath</a></td><td>"
                    . $row['F']. "</td><td>"
                    . "<a href='download.php?type=F&path=". $fullFPath. "'> $fullFPath</a></td><td>"
                    . $row['G']. "</td><td>"
                    . "<a href='download.php?type=G&path=". $fullGPath . "'> $fullGPath </a></td>"
                    . "<td><button class='Retry' id='retryBtn'>Retry</button></td>";//button here
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        ?>
```

JQuery

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    'use strict';
    $(document).ready(function(){//code not run at all.
        $("#report").load(function(){
        console.log('here');
        var retryBtn = document.getElementById('retry');
        //retryBtn.style.visibility = "hidden";
        
        var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
        var status = currentRow.find(".status");
        
        if(status == "Failed")
        {
            retryBtn.style.display = "block";
        }else{
            retryBtn.style.display = "none";
        };  
       });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: change to $(document).ready

Comment: @bobi it still the same result btw, i have tried it with `$(document).ready` before. so it doesnt work for me

Comment: How you add JQuery.js in Html?

Comment: `<script src="../src/inc/jQuery.js"></script>` in `<head>`  @KavithaKT
the source i got from this url http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js

Comment: use    $('#report').load(function(){    } along with $(document).ready

Comment: Another issue is that the DOM can only have ONE unique `id` name specified, so having multiple buttons with the same `retryBtn` as the id will only reference the first button having that id.

Comment: @PaulT. that also one of the issues i encounter as well. How do I solve that?

Comment: Use class instead

Comment: @KavithaKT could you show how to use class in this case?